# Problemas com parâmetros nas rotas API (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, route

Olá!

Estou iniciando os estudos em api rest. Na minha aplicação só posso retornar os dados do funcionário de acordo com a id da empresa que ele pertence, porém, a api está retornando os dados independente da id da empresa que eu passe como parametro.

Exemplo:

Rota

```
api/company/company_id/employee/employee_id
```

Se passo os parametros:

```
api/company/2/employee/3
```

Ela me retorna os dados corretos!

Porém, seu faço isso:

```
api/company/qualquercoisa/employee/3
```

Continua retornando os mesmos dados.

Como eu limito a rota para que só passe os dados do funcionário de acordo com a id da empresa a qual ele pertence?

Meu código:

Controller

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Employee;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;



class EmployeesController extends Controller
{

    public function getEmployee(Request $request)
    {


        return Employee::findOrFail($request->employee_id); 

    }


}
```

Model

```php
class Employee extends Model
{
      protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'position',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'admission',
        'company_id'
    ];

   

      public function company(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Company','company_id','id');
    }

  
}
```

Route

```php
Route::get('api/company/{company_id}/employee/{employee_id}','EmployeesController@getEmployee');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara o Laravel possui uma maneira de utilização de regex para restringir rotas, uma forma de fazer isso é adicionando um where:

```
Route::get('user/{id}',SomeController@someFunction)->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Isso é aconselhável pois diminui as chances de passar dados em formatos não desejados.

Quanto a sua questão de somente passar as informações do funcionário se o mesmo for da instituição informada, é algo que deve ser tratado em seu Controller, verificando se a instituição do funcionário é igual ao dado informado na URL. Um exemplo disso seria:

```
$employee = Employee::findOrFail($request->employee_id);
if($employee->company_id == $request->company_id)
   return $employee;
abort(404);
```

Note que utilizei um lançamento de erro do Laravel informando o erro 404 de página não existente, outros tipos de erros podem ser lançados.

### Referências

[Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

[HTTP Exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#http-exceptions)

Comment: cara muitoooo obrigado! Era isso mesmo, além de ter solucionado, seu codigo esclareceu uma lógica que eu achei que tinha entendido, mas estava pensando de maneira errada! @LuanMichel

Comment: Show!! Se puder marcar a resposta como aceita, assim o seu questionamento é dado como respondido. @Lucasmoore

Comment: sim, acabei me passando! Valeu! @LuanMichel